# Python run exe from memory

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctf

```
exe = requests.get(url).content
run_exe = subprocess.run(exe, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT).stdout.read()
print(run_exe.stdout.decode(encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore'))
```

So I know that it is not that simple to execute this but,
it is the basic concept
I am trying to run an EXE file that has been loaded into memory without saving it to the disk.
it is part of the CTF tool that I have building

https://github.com/BlackSnufkin/LuckyCheck

Answer (score 1):

a nice module to save files to memory would be 'memory-tempfile' depending on your exact needs it should do you good to check it out:

https://pypi.org/project/memory-tempfile/

Comment: thank man learn something new from that, but still not exactly what I need i